# How can I print usernames in order using entity_load function?

Tags: 7, users

I'm using drupal 7.28, and I have fetched user id using `entity_load('user')`, so I need descending sorting on usernames using this way of logic, let me know if anyone has an idea.Here is my code that I have written in my file.

```
$users = entity_load('user',$sort);
$usersIds = array_keys($users);
foreach($usersIds as $usrId)
{    
   $user = user_load($usrId);
   $user_load_name = array($user->name);
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($user_load_name);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest updating your Drupal site to 7.34. See https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2014-005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

small change in your code will do it for you

```
$users = entity_load('user');//load all user in your site
$usersIds = array_keys($users); // get all uid of the user
foreach($usersIds as $usrId) {
    $user = user_load($usrId); 
    $user_load_name = $user->name;//get the user name
    $user_load_name1[] = $user_load_name;// store all user name in array 
 }
 natcasesort($user_load_name1);//For sorting array in ascending order INCASE SENCITIVE order
 $arr = array_reverse($user_load_name1, true);// For making it in descending
```

This code will only give the user name in Decending order if you want it in ascending order just remove array_reverse() line that will be enough.

hope it helps you :)

Comment: Yes, working perfect :)